# Unexpected behavior when using dictionary with multithreading in swift

Tags: swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, race-condition

I'm attempting to perform numerous asynchronous activities using dispatch queues. My biggest challenge was to have the threads access a dictionary while keeping it safe with an NSLOCK. At the start of my code, I initialized the dictionary so that it didn't have any nil values, and then the threads started accessing it. However, at some point, some threads read the value of the optional got from the dictionary as nil, even though it had been initialized and some previous threads accessed the same index and modified its value by simply subtracting one from it, making it impossible to turn to nil.

I suspected a race condition, so I converted the dictionary to a standard array using the same locking method, and everything worked properly on over 50 runs, and all of the final values saved on the array were consistent, indicating that no race condition occurred.

So, why did using the dictionary with the same locking technique cause certain threads to read the optional value as nil after a while?

Comment: I’d first suggest temporarily using TSAN with your dictionary rendition first, to make sure you do not have any data races. See “Detect Data Races Among Your App’s Threads” section of [Diagnosing Memory, Thread, and Crash Issues Early](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-memory-thread-and-crash-issues-early/). If you do not have a strict data race, then you might just have some logic race or other bug. We obviously cannot diagnose without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Value types are intended to be thread safe by nature--they're copied when needed and passed around by value to avoid unintended sharing. Reference types are the objects that are typically configured for synchronized shared access. I'd consider making this shared value type a property of a class, perhaps, and tasking this wrapper with managing the shared access. Just two cents. And definitely familiarize yourself with the thread sanitizer.

Comment: The fact that a particular configuration (using an array, for example) doesn't show a particular symptom doesn't mean there's no data race. Arrays are simpler than Dictionaries, and while they're still not thread-safe, certain operations may "work" in certain tests that fail using Dictionaries. Once you engage in undefined behavior (such as accessing a value type from multiple threads without synchronization), what happens is undefined. "Seems to work" is one thing that undefined behavior can do. Your code is still likely buggy.